# VBS ftp download wait time

Tags: vbscript, ftp

I am writing a script in VBS that downloads a file from an FTP server and the processes it. I have this bunch of code that is working correctly:

```
path = evidenceFolder
On Error Resume Next
Const copyType = 16

Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'FTP Wait Time in ms
waitTime = 3000000

strFTP = "ftp://" & FTPUser & ":" & FTPPass & "@" & FTPHost & FTPDir & FTPRoute
Set objFTP = oShell.NameSpace(strFTP)

'Download all files in folder
If objFSO.FolderExists(path) Then
    'Entire folder
    Set objFolder = oShell.NameSpace(path)
    objFolder.CopyHere objFTP.Items, copyType
End If
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Wscript.Echo "Error: " & Err.Description &  " - " & Err.Number
End If
'Wait for upload
Wscript.Sleep waitTime
```

If I don't set the appropriate wait time processing of the files starts before the download is complete. As I have to download big files I need to set a high value for the waiting time. If the download is not so big it just keeps waiting for a too long time.

Is there a way of just waiting just for the download to finish, and not an arbitrary and constant time?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve it by changing the way of doing the FTP. I have downloaded Winscp and used it as command line ftp client, as the windows client does not acept the pasive mode and was generating FW issues.

```
Const ForWriting = 2
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set sessionFile = objFso.OpenTextFile("session.txt", ForWriting, vbTrue)
With sessionFile
    .WriteLine "open ftp://user:pass@xx.xx.xx.xx"
    .WriteLine "cd " & FTPDir & FTPRoute
    .WriteLine "get *.* " & destFolder & "\"
    .WriteLine "exit"
    .Close
End With
strFTP = "tools\winscp577\winscp.com /script=session.txt"
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strFTP = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(strFTP)
WshShell.Run strFTP,, vbTrue
objFso.DeleteFile "session.txt", vbTrue
```